# Update data in two Sheets Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to update data on two sheets that is Sheet1 and Sheet2 data is available in same rows and same column in both sheets

i use this update code

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
    Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(TB1.Text,startdate.Text, enddate.Text, ComboB.Text)
    End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, let's say you want this to run on "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", same cells.  Just add the sheet you want it to update before the `Cells()`: `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value` then just copy/paste and change to "Sheet2".

Comment: @Muhammad Khurrum Butt Agree with Bruce Wayne i just tested it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the sheet you want it to update before the Cells(): `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value` then just copy/paste and change to "Sheet2":

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(TB1.Text,startdate.Text, enddate.Text, ComboB.Text)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(currentrow - 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array(TB1.Text,startdate.Text, enddate.Text, ComboB.Text)
End Sub
```